# Объявление функции внутри структуры и ее реализация извне

Tags: c++, struct

у меня есть одна проблема. Существует у меня такая структура, как Attributes

```
struct Attributes
{
    int attackNearMin;
    int attackNearMax;
    int attackLongMin;
    int attackLongMax;
    int armor;
    int health;
    int speed;
    int x;
    int y;

    void specialAttack(specialAttackArgs args);
};
```

В ней есть функция specialAttack, я ее только объявляю. Дальше я создаю несколько объектов таких структур и мне надо, чтобы у каждого объекта была своя реализация этой функции. Могу ли я это как-то сделать? Если да, то как?

Comment: Как-то нелогично, нет? Тогда уж делать функцию, которая получает объект, и в зависимости от него выполняет те или иные действия?

Comment: @Harry тут все чуточку сложнее. У меня есть std::map, в котором в виде ключа выступает enum с классами героев (их там около 36), а в виде значения выступает эта структура (некие характеристики героя). Если делать так, как вы сказали, то тогда мне придется делать кучу условий (около 36 апхапх). Если я смогу сделать реализацию функции извне структуры, то я просто пропишу все эти 36 функций, а потом буду получать нужную мне структуру и вызывать у нее функцию. Я не гуру, учусь, но мне кажется, что с функциями получится легче

Comment: `void (*specialAttack)(specialAttackArgs args);` - переменная `specialAttack` будет указателем на функцию.

Comment: @Cominta ещё один вариант решения проблемы - хранить в классе героя универсальную ссылку на callback, который можно толкнуть в конструктор класса героя. И внутри specialAttack вызывать этот callback. Такой вариант гораздо лучше определения 36 новых классов, но тогда класс героя станет шаблонным. В целом это не недостаток, но потребует знаний о perfect-forwarding (впрочем если вы стремитесь стать хорошим плюсовиком, то вам это в любом случае 100% понадобится)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете, но не с таким объявлением функции.

Сначала делаете так:

```
std::function<void(specialAttackArgs args)> specialAttack; // Здесь `args` можно не писать.
```

Потом вот так:

```
int main()
{
    Attributes a;
    a.specialAttack = [](specialAttackArgs args)
    {
        // Тут тело функции.
    };
}
```

Или так:

```
void myAttack(specialAttackArgs args)
{
    // Тут тело функции.
}

int main()
{
    Attributes a;
    a.specialAttack = myAttack;
}
```

Comment: Attributes a;
a.specialAttack = [](specialAttackArgs args)
{
        
}

попробовал ваш код, компилятор выдает такую ошибку: error: 'a' does not name a type

Comment: @Cominta Полный код покажите.

Comment: извиняюсь, я немного затупил хапхпа. спасибо огромное за помощь, сработало!